# Segmented Control Elegance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-6, segmentedcontrol

I'm coding for the iPhone 6 in Objective C, and I'm coding an Image View that changes when the user presses three buttons on a Segmented Control. My code is working correctly, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to get UISegmentedControl to cycle UIImageView between three images. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this than defining a new image object in each new switch case? Here is the relevant code:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView;

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (IBAction)myControls:(id)sender {
UISegmentedControl *ctrl =
    (UISegmentedControl *)
    sender;

switch([ctrl selectedSegmentIndex])
{
    case 0:
    {UIImage *image =
        [UIImage imageNamed: @"picture.tiff"];
        self.myImageView.image = image;}
        break;
    case 1:
    {UIImage *image1 =
        [UIImage imageNamed: @"picture1.tiff"];
        self.myImageView.image = image1;}
        break;
    case 2:
    {UIImage *image2 =
        [UIImage imageNamed: @"picture2.tiff"];
        self.myImageView.image = image2;}
        break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If images are same at fixed index, you can store them in NSArray as:

```
NSArray * imageNames = @[ @"picture.tiff", @"picture1.tiff", @"picture2.tiff" ];
```

And then:

```
- (IBAction) myControls: (UISegmentedControl *) segmentedControl
{
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: imageNames[segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex]];
   self.myImageView.image = image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tiffs are pretty small in memory, place them each in three `UIImageViews` with identical frames.  To show one of them, make only one the three visible at a time.

Give each image view a tag, say 32, 33, and 34.  Instead of your singular `myImageView` property, keep an array, called `myImageViews`.  Then a method to make just one visible:

```
- (void)showImageViewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag {
    for (UIImageView *imageView in self. myImageViews) {
        imageView.alpha = (imageView.tag == tag)? 1.0 : 0.0;
    }
}
```

Call that once when you initialize your UI. And finally, when the user changes the switch:

```
- (IBAction)myControls:(UIView *)sender {
    [self showImageViewWithTag:sender.tag+32]
}
```